# Trouble definding NPm dependancies inside local package

Tags: meteor

I am trying to create a package, but I cannot require npm modules inside the package. This results in a

```
Cannot find module '..path../crypto'
```

/packages/s3policy/lib/s3policy.js

```
crypto = Npm.require('crypto');

S3Policy = {};

S3Policy.readPolicy...
```

/packages/s3policy/package.js

```
Npm.depends({
  'crypto': '0.0.3'
});

Package.describe({
  name: 's3policy',
  summary: 'S3 policy API',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('lib/s3policy.js', ['server']);
  api.export('S3Policy');
});
```

Any idea as to why I am unable to require the crypto module?

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this helps](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2050)?

> crypto is a built in node package (http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). It doesn't need to be installed. However, the npm crypto package is 2 year old unmaintained code that is often downloaded by mistake (https://www.npmjs.org/package/crypto). Either Meteor or NPM gets confused because the packages have the same name, but it doesn't really matter because you don't want the NPM package.

Just take crypto out of your npm packages and you should be fine.